# How to reset netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege?

Tags: javascript, firefox

At same point, I believe I've clicked the "Deny" button when the message box appeared in FireFox asking me if I wanted to allow a site a privilege using the

```
netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege()
```

method. Now, I cannot find how to reset this so that the message box will start appearing again at this specific site. I've checked Tools -> Options and about:config, but nothing. Does anyone know how to reset this? Or is there any other reason that the message box simply will not show and automatically throw an exception?

Answer (score 3):

Firefox saves the allow/deny permissions for websites using PrivilegeManager in the prefs.js file in your profile directory. A permanent DENY setting for the sample page (jar:http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/signed-script-demo.jar!/signed-script-demo.html) added these user preferences:

```
user_pref("capability.principal.certificate.p0.denied", "UniversalPreferencesRead");
user_pref("capability.principal.certificate.p0.id", "C3:B3:11:2F:F2:CB:3B:86:A3:66:11:DD:C2:42:0F:7F:98:C8:21:02");
user_pref("capability.principal.certificate.p0.subjectName", "CN=Netscape Communications Corp.,OU=For internal testing only,O=Netscape Communications Corp.,L=Mountain View,ST=California,C=US");
```

You'll have to find the ones for the website that you accidentally denied, and delete the three settings for that site.  Exit Firefox before you change them, or it will get overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools -> Clear Recent History -> press the details button, check Site Preferences/Settings(I dont know how it is in english, but you will find the right checkbox easy) and then click Erase Now(or Ok, whatever).